# How to configure Apache shiro with spring boot in a separate module?

Tags: spring-boot, shiro, spring-boot-maven-plugin

My spring boot project contains more than 10 modules, with Cassandra DB. i want to do the security with the separate module. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a little more info. Are you just looking to keep your security code in a separate maven/gradle module?  If so that would work just like any other project, you shouldn't need anything specific.

Comment: yes. separate maven module. because, In some cases i need to change parent maven project. So if it is in separate module which is more convenient to me....

Comment: how to write custom realm for the application? shiro.ini is only enough or any other class/interface needs to implement for achieve shiro authentication?

Comment: Take a look at https://shiro.apache.org/realm.html - You can use any of the existing Realms as a guide (if you can explain your use case a bit more someone might be able to get you a better link)

Comment: Thanks Brian, I have 3 roles, ADMIN,USER,GUEST. here i need to create realm for Cassandra db. how can i start this configuration ?

Comment: Take a look at: http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/13ccsk1ky4/password-authentication-advice

Comment: Brian, i want to authenticate and authorize my page using apache shiro. Still I have no idea how to start this implementation. Because UI pages are in separate microservice, and shiro authentication will be in separate microsevice. How can I authenticate a page, on every hit of login?

Comment: It depends, these are really broad questions without many details. You may want to start a new thread.

Comment: I am also struggling with the similar kind of issue. Actually, I have 10 modules in a spring boot application and one module is responsible for security. In Security module (JAR), I am using Apache Shiro and JWT (as a token provider). Till the basic authentication, everything works fine But after getting Token, When I am calling my current module's endpoint by passing Bearer token, after validating token it is throwing 404 ( My Spring controller endpoints are not found). Is there any additional configuration required in Shiro filter?

Comment: My configurations are below:

`@Bean
public ShiroFilterChainDefinition shiroFilterChainDefinition() {
        DefaultShiroFilterChainDefinition chainDefinition = new 
        DefaultShiroFilterChainDefinition();
        chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/JWTProvider/**", 
                "authcBasic[permissive]");
        chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/api/**", "jwtv");
        return chainDefinition;
}`

Comment: Im still not started with shiro. From UIService, I submitted login details, then using feign clients uiserivce is communicating with authenticationservice. I am going to write shiro implementation in authentication service. My doubt is, i need to write shiro.ini and realm class or any other bean to inject?

Comment: Please open new threads, we would love to help but there are a couple different questions here

Comment: Thank you brian, I will create a new thread. And one more I have configured authenticatication service with feign clients(separate module).